# Telegram bot API method answerCallbackQuery i added in bot but now it dosen't show alerts what to do?

Tags: php

Well my bot is in php I simply coded it with some inline buttons now I want to add answer callback query but it doesn't show alerts

I set it true but still no alerts getting.

Tell any solution for it and also provide function answerCallbackQuery and full code of what to put in url and how I can see the alerts in bot Hope You understand that.

Thanks for your help in advance xD

Comment: Edit your question, add your code that try to response to callback query (that not works)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First detect the callback query using `$in['callback_query']['data']`
Then try to response it something like :

```
call(
    'answerCallbackQuery',
    [
        'callback_query_id' => $in['callback_query']['id'],
        'text' => $msg,
        'show_alert' => 1,
    ]
);
```

- The `call` is a sample function to try send request using `file_get_contents` for example
- And `$in` is the recieved data from telegram request that decoded as array

---

## UPDATE

To restrict it for all users except some users, you can do it like :

```php
$user_id = $in['message']['from']['id'];

$approved = ['666666','77777'];


if( in_array($user_id, $approved) ){
    $msg = 'Approved';
    // do something ...
}else{
    $msg = 'Error';
}


call(
    'answerCallbackQuery',
    [
        'callback_query_id' => $in['callback_query']['id'],
        'text' => $msg,
        'show_alert' => 1,
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thanks bro working but 1 more question how I restrict it like it only edit for approved users and for non approved it say not available in answercallbackquery

Comment: The answer was updated, you may set the answer as accepted if it solve your problem